# centOS6.8にphpMyAdminをyumでインストールしたさいのエラー

Tags: centos, phpmyadmin, yum

サーバー構築初心者で初歩的な質問かもしれませんがすいません。
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
【サーバー情報】
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
x86_64（64bit）
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.37
PHP 5.6.28
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

PHPとmysqlをアップデートした後、改めてphpMyAdminを導入しようとしたのですが、
以下のコマンドで実行し、

```
yum install phpMyAdmin
```

エラーが以下のようにでてインストールできません

```
    121 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
依存性の解決をしています
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.20-1.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts のパッケージ: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-tcpdf のパッケージ: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-php-gettext のパッケージ: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.12-1.el6 will be インストール
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-tidy のパッケージ: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-bcmath のパッケージ: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6 will be インストール
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 のパッケージ: php-bcmath-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 のパッケージ: php-tidy-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。
エラー: パッケージ: php-bcmath-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
             要求: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
            インストール: php-common-5.6.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.28-1.el6.remi
            利用可能: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
            利用可能: php56u-common-5.6.31-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.ius.el6
            利用可能: php70u-common-7.0.22-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.22-2.ius.el6
            利用可能: php71u-common-7.1.8-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.8-2.ius.el6
エラー: パッケージ: php-tidy-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
             要求: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
            インストール: php-common-5.6.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.28-1.el6.remi
            利用可能: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
            利用可能: php56u-common-5.6.31-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.ius.el6
            利用可能: php70u-common-7.0.22-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.22-2.ius.el6
            利用可能: php71u-common-7.1.8-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.8-2.ius.el6
 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができません
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

アドバイスをいただけるとありがたく存じます

追記：お返事ありがとうございます
yum repolistを実行してみた結果ですm(_ _)m

```
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                 | 6.6 kB     00:00     
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * ius: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
base                                                                                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
ius                                                                                                                                                           | 2.3 kB     00:00     
mysql-connectors-community                                                                                                                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00     
mysql-tools-community                                                                                                                                         | 2.5 kB     00:00     
mysql56-community                                                                                                                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00     
remi-safe                                                                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00     
121 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
リポジトリー ID                                                      リポジトリー名                                                                                        状態
base                                                                 CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                            6,706
epel                                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                        12,269+111
extras                                                               CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                             45
ius                                                                  IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                     406+1
mysql-connectors-community                                           MySQL Connectors Community                                                                                  34+8
mysql-tools-community                                                MySQL Tools Community                                                                                         51
mysql56-community                                                    MySQL 5.6 Community Server                                                                                   377
remi-safe                                                            Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                               2,179+1
updates                                                              CentOS-6 - Updates
```

追記2:ありがとう御座いましたm(_ _)m
解決いたしました
もっとリポジトリについて学びたいと思います

Comment: 念のため 'yum repolist' でリポジトリの一覧を確認の上、追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOSはRHELをベースにしているため、標準でインストール出来るパッケージは安定性を重視しており
必ずしも各アプリケーションの"最新版"とは限りません。

http://vault.centos.org/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages/php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64.rpm

CentOS 6.8向けのPHPはv5.3.3が提供されていますが、より新しいバージョン(v5.6.28)に更新するため
REMIリポジトリからインストールしたのだと思います。

REMIリポジトリでは最新のバージョンが利用できる反面、CentOS本来のリポジトリにあるパッケージと
コンフリクト(衝突)を起こす可能性があるため、必要時のみ有効にしての利用が推奨されています。

今回の場合であれば以下の様に再度REMIリポジトリのみを有効にした状態でphpMyAdminパッケージの
インストールを試してみてください。

```
# yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 update
# yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

php-5.6.28 をインストールした際、remi, remi-php56 リポジトリを有効にして yum install したのではありませんか？

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: はい、リポジトリを有効にした覚えが有ります。phpのアップデートのインストールの際にに手間取り、調べてその方法に行き着きました。お恥ずかしいですがリポジトリの概念自体がよく分かっていません、